# How to make confirm dialog modal in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to confirm for delete row in table but not use confirm default in Angular.

Comment: Refer this [**medium post**](https://medium.com/@aravind_12433/load-modal-component-dynamically-in-angular-5fda8e1dc3e7)

Comment: @Aravind  your link does not open. please check it out :)

Comment: Still it's not working for my side! may be it's my local proxy problem. :) \

Comment: @RameshRajendran Link works just fine, btw it's PrimeNG, not priming.

Comment: @msmolcic ha ha ha ! I found a man with eagle eye's :p . I have update in my answer :) thanks for your notify dude

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [primeng confirm Dialogue box](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/confirmdialog)

**html (Use p-confirbox directive)**

```
<p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="fa fa-question-circle" width="425"></p-confirmDialog>

<button type="text" (click)="confirm()" pButton icon="fa-check" label="Confirm"></button>
```

**Import primeng in your component and call the confirm box by below way**

```
import {ConfirmDialogModule,ConfirmationService} from 'primeng/primeng';

export class ConfirmDialogDemo { 

    constructor(private confirmationService: ConfirmationService) {}

    confirm() {
        this.confirmationService.confirm({
            message: 'Are you sure that you want to perform this action?',
            accept: () => {
                //Actual logic to perform a confirmation
            }
        });
    }
}
```